# What do parentheses mean within angle brackets for a Boost signal?

Tags: c++, templates, parentheses, boost-signals2

In my basic c++ book, there is no class declaration like below.
the strange code for me is ...

```
boost::signals2::signal<bool (const std::string& message, 
const std::string& caption, unsigned int style),
boost::signals2::last_value<bool> > ThreadSafeMessageBox;
```

the things in round brackets (`const std:::string`...) are not a typename but instance. How could it be possible? The code above compiles fine.

p.s. template class (`signal`) code is

```
template<typename Signature,
  typename Combiner = optional_last_value<typename boost::function_traits<Signature>::result_type>,
  typename Group = int,
  typename GroupCompare = std::less<Group>,
  typename SlotFunction = function<Signature>,
  typename ExtendedSlotFunction = typename detail::extended_signature<function_traits<Signature>::arity, Signature>::function_type,
  typename Mutex = mutex >
class signal: public detail::signalN<function_traits<Signature>::arity,
  Signature, Combiner, Group, GroupCompare, SlotFunction, ExtendedSlotFunction, Mutex>::type
{ /*...*};
```

Comment: Not a good idea to highlight a part of C++ code with `**`.

Comment: It is a function type

Answer (score 3):

Check out the documentation for [Boost.Signals2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/signals2.html#idp609285728):

> The Boost.Signals2 library is an implementation of a managed signals and slots system. **Signals represent callbacks with multiple targets**

So we know that a "signal" has something to do with "callbacks". A [callback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)) is a function to call at a later time.

So, then check out the ["Hello World"](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/signals2/tutorial.html#idp609295808) example in the documentation:

```
struct HelloWorld
{
  void operator()() const
  {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
  }
};
// ...

  // Signal with no arguments and a void return value
  boost::signals2::signal<void ()> sig;

  // Connect a HelloWorld slot
  HelloWorld hello;
  sig.connect(hello);

  // Call all of the slots
  sig();
```

> First, we create a signal `sig`, a signal that takes no arguments and has a `void` return value. Next, we connect the `hello` function object to the signal using the `connect` method. Finally, use the signal `sig` like a function to call the slots, which in turns invokes `HelloWorld::operator()` to print "Hello, World!".

After reading all this, what can we deduce? We can deduce that the template argument to a signal is a **function type**. It indicates the kind of function that can be connected to the signal.

So, in your example

```
boost::signals2::signal<bool (const std::string& message, 
                             const std::string& caption, 
                             unsigned int style), 
                        boost::signals2::last_value<bool> 
                       > ThreadSafeMessageBox;
```

`ThreadSafeMessageBox` is a signal that can connect to a function that:

- returns `bool`
- takes a first argument of `const std::string&`
- takes a second argument of `const std::string&`
- takes a third argument of `unsigned int`

(The second template argument we can ignore for the purposes of this question, it is not a required template argument nor is it part of the callback function signature, but rather something called a [Combiner](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/signals2/reference.html#header.boost.signals2.signal_hpp))

Answer (score 0):

The type expected as template parameter `Signature` is a function signature, that is the specification of the expected function parameters number, types and return type.

In your case

```
boost::signals2::signal<bool (const std::string& message, const std::string& caption, unsigned int style), boost::signals2::last_value<bool> > ThreadSafeMessageBox;
```

the first parameter for the template `boost::signals2::signal` is the function signature:

```
bool (const std::string& message, const std::string& caption, unsigned int style)
```

that is a function with 3 parameters (of type `string`, `string` and `unsigned int`) and returning a `bool`.